# How to Create the API for MEAN application

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean

Hello I am new  in MEAN application and I am creating login form and I did R&D and

Got the dummy project there I easily  signup and login But I am confused

regarding code of API which is using  location is:-

```
                     public/js/controller/controller.js

$scope.loginpage = function(){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/login',
          data: {email:$scope.email, password:$scope.password}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if(response.data.error)
            {
                alert("Invalid email pasword");
            }
            else 
            {

                $scope.dp = response.data;
                $localStorage.pp = $scope.dp;
                //console.log($localStorage.pp)
                $location.path('/addseat');

            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          alert("Invalid email pasword");
        });
    }
```

it working properly and I want to description  of this code where url is :-

```
                      url: '/api/login',
```

But In whole app no API folder I don't konw how to get this particular folder.

and my doubt is here **what is api folder or file**

Comment: The `/api/login` is a reference to a url exposed by the server that when you `POST` to it this object: `{email:$scope.email, password:$scope.password}` you will perform a login. Perhaps all you miss is actually running the server.

Comment: @MuliYulzary Actually working is fine and login successfully but i don't know which file is using the backend functionality for login "url mention path" where is login file?

Comment: There is no login file. It's a virtual path on the server.

Comment: But where backend  login functionality mention on node js please help me defiantly something depend on the url path